# what is the correct syntax to use tryremove and byref in F#

Tags: f#

I have the following:

```
let callbacks = ConcurrentDictionary<string, Object>()
```

I'm trying to use TryRemove:

```
if callbacks.TryRemove(id, myObject : byref<Object>) then ...
```

that doesn't compile; I tried too:

```
let mutable cc = Object
if callbacks.TryRemove(id, ref cc) then ...
```

but same thing.. and that:

```
let mutable cc = Object
if callbacks.TryRemove(id, &cc) then ...
```

what is the correct syntax to use this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler rewrites the function here to a return type like `TryRemove: string -> (bool, obj)`, so you can interact with it using a match:

```
match d.TryRemove "blah" with
| true, o -> //do something with o
| false, _ -> // in this case o is the default value of Object, so is useless
```

if you don't want to match you can use a let:

```
let found, v = d.TryRemove "blah"
```

though this way lies peril if you forget to check the value of `found` before using `v`, which is why I recommend the match. It keeps the scope of `o` as tight as possible.

Comment: @Thomas Note that you can also do `let mutable cc : obj = null` and `if callbacks.TryRemove(id, &cc) then ...`, if you need/want to use the long syntax, though I agree with Chet that this is a much cleaner approach.